# Connection to the internet using 3g modem ZTE MF190 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, usb-modem, 3g

I got problem with using 3G modem in Ubuntu.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox and use it as guest OS. My host OS is Windows 7. I haven't problem when share hosts internet via NAT, but when i'm connecting 3g usb modem though virtualbox to my virtual machine i can't create internet connection.
 What am i doing?

1)I stick modem to USB port and start **lsusb**

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
:~$
```

2)start **dmesg | tail**

```
:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 2653.255382] option 1-1:1.3: device disconnected
[ 2653.559296] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 2664.265542] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 2664.268304] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 2664.268509] option 1-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 2664.270277] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 2664.270469] option 1-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 2664.272902] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 2664.273051] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 2664.273208] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
:~$
```

I thought that here was device as modem detected, but when i tryed 
 **dmesg | grep ZTE**:

```
:~$ dmesg | grep ZTE
[ 1440.974586] usb 1-1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
[ 1440.974588] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 1440.974589] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: MF1900ZTED010000
[ 1442.189100] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 2616.073844] usb 1-1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
[ 2616.073846] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 2616.073848] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: MF1900ZTED010000
[ 3633.625971] usb 1-1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
[ 3633.625976] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 3633.625980] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: MF1900ZTED010000
[ 3634.642422] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
:~$
```

Here device detected as CD-ROM

3)start **sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x19d2 -p 0x2003 -K**

```
:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x19d2 -p 0x2003 -K
Look for default devices
product ID matched
Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 004 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
USB description data (for identification)
   Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
     Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: MF1900ZTED010000
Sending standard EJECT sequence
Looking for active driver 
 No active driver found. Detached before or never attached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending 
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) 
 Response reading failed (error -7)
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

4) Try **lsusb** but vip:pid of device not changed

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
:~$
```

5) Create Mobile Broadband connection, but no success

6) I tryed Modem Manager GUI

(http://saveimg.ru/pictures/26-05-16/cb26d0e126b83cdfc39bc2c4cfad9766.png)
but got error

http://saveimg.ru/pictures/26-05-16/91609535d0583c4592bd723233ba82c9.png